# Closed timelike curves

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, causality

In a paper, I have read that the manifold

$$S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^n$$

with the metric $g=-d \theta^2 +g_0$, where $-d \theta$ is the standard metric on $S^1$ and $g_0$ is the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ always possesses closed causal curves.

Is the reasoning behind this that each closed curve along the unit circle is a closed timelike curve?

Comment: Do you mean $S^1$ or $S^2$?

Comment: "Yes", that is correct for this metric.

Comment: For the metric $g= d \theta+g_0$ it wouldn't be correct, right?

Comment: The metric $d\theta^2 + g_0$ doesn't have the right signature for relativity...?

Comment: Forget about my comment, I don't know what I was thinking